# git hooks - regenerate a file and add it to each commit?

Tags: git, githooks

I'd like to automatically generate a file and add it to a commit if it has changed. Is it possible, if so, what hooks should I use?

Context: I'm programming a CSS library. It has several CSS files, and at the end I want to produce a compacted and minimized version. Right now my workflow is:

1. Modify the css files `x.css` and `y.css`
2. `git add x.css y.css`
3. Execute `minimize.sh` which parses all the css files on my lib, minimizes them and produces a `min.css` file
4. `git add min.css`
5. `git commit -m 'modified x and y doing foo and bar'`

I would like to have steps 3 and 4 done automatically via a git hook. Is that possible?

I've never used git hooks before. After reading the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), I think I need to use the `pre-commit` hook. But can I invoke `git add min.css`, or will I break the internet?

EDIT: It worked! And I didn't create a black hole or anything!

Here's the code of my .git/hooks/pre-commit file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec minimize.sh
exec git add oocss.min.css
```

The documentation didn't mention that I had to make it executable, or it would not work.

In case you are interested in how did I minimize, I used [juicer](https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer) - the minimizing command is:

```
exec juicer merge --force my-uncompressed-file.css
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it won’t break anything. You can freely use `git add` in a `pre-commit` hook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel like an evil genious now. Buahahahaha. Launch missiles!

Comment: git add is not working for me either in pre-commit hook, it adds file for next commit, not current one.

Comment: The file is **actually** added that is `git add` in `pre-commit`, but the commit message shown in `vim` editor does not include it.

Comment: Same here, `git add` in pre-commit is cockblocked  with an `index.lock`... @Aristotle Pagaltzis Can you elaborate how to achive your solution, sir?